# Why doesn't my pygame window close on MacOS?

Tags: python, pygame, macos

I am trying to create a window and then close the window. Everything runs smoothly until I click the red X. When I click it, the window doesn't close and all that happens is that the colourful red beach ball thing shows up whenever I hover my mouse over the Pygame window and the window just does not respond.

It seems like the `pygame.quit()` or `pygame.display.quit()` functions do not work for some reason.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
Window=pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
run=True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
pygame.quit()
pygame.display.quit()
```

[image: This is a copy of the window that shows up when I run the code]
[image: This is a picture of the console showing that there is not any error with the code]

Comment: In the future, please post code as text instead of images. That way people can quickly try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Try to draw something like a coloured background to the window, also, Why are you using pygame.display.quit()?
pygame.quit() alone would do the work.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct code:

```
from pygame.locals import *

import sys,pygame

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((200, 100))

pygame.display.set_caption("hello")

while(True):

   for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type==QUIT:

            pygame.quit()

            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Why is that the correct code? What's missing in the OPs implementation?

Answer (score -2):

Well instead of declaring run as variable you can just
do it like this:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
```

`enter code here`

```
while 1:
 for event in pygame.event.get()
  if event.type == QUIT:
   pygame.quit();sys.exit()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, but just points out an unrelated thing.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thanks for contributing. As mentioned, this doesn't seem to address OP's core problem & as such it seems more like a comment than an answer. There is a small rep limit before you can comment, but attempting to get around that by posting as answer rarely works out well. If you *did* intend this more as a comment than a stand alone solution to the problem, flag your answer with a brief explanation for the mods.